# Android TextView AutoScroll

Tags: android, textview, autoscroll

I am trying to implement autoscroll in textviews in a table layout. I see that autoscroll is happening only for first textview box and not for all boxes.

```
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/GuessWordtableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#d65906" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/GuessWordtextView1a"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dip"
                android:background="#fcc480"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="1dip"
                android:text="1" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/GuessWordtextView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:layout_margin="1dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#fcc480"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="1dip"
                android:text="This is a very big statement which has to scroll" >

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/GuessWordtextView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:layout_margin="1dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="#fcc480"
                android:padding="1dip"
                android:text="This is a very big statement which has to scroll" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/GuessWordtextView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:layout_margin="1dip"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="#fcc480"
                android:padding="1dip"
                android:text="This is a very big statement which has to scroll" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>
```

This is what I have. I see that text is scrolling only for textview id GuessWordtextView11 and not for GuessWordtextView12 and GuessWordtextView13. What could be the reason?

Comment: please see my answer and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 2):

change to/add this proprieties to the TextViews :

```
android:gravity="bottom"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is same. I only see the first textview autosrolling. The other two are static.

Comment: please try to remove  android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" for a bit and try with that . @user2901219

Answer (score 0):

Enclose with `<ScrollView>`

Comment: I guess you mentioning the code as below. it is not autoscrolling.

Answer (score 0):

***Scrolling*** for all **TextView**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/GuessWordtableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="1dip"
    android:background="#d65906" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/GuessWordtextView1a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dip"
            android:background="#fcc480"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="1dip"
            android:text="@string/long_string" >
        </TextView>
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/GuessWordtextView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dip"
            android:background="#fcc480"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="1dip"
            android:text="@string/long_string"  >

        </TextView>
    </ScrollView>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/GuessWordtextView12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dip"
            android:background="#fcc480"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="1dip"
            android:text="@string/long_string"  >

        </TextView>
    </ScrollView>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/GuessWordtextView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dip"
            android:background="#fcc480"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="1dip"
            android:text="@string/long_string"  >

        </TextView>
    </ScrollView>

</TableRow>
```

Comment: What is saw previuosly using ScrollView is we can manually scroll, but it doesnt autoscroll.

Comment: my exaple is vertical scrolling